# Cartesian plane using java, cannot find symbol error

Tags: java

I know someone else has had a very similar problem to me and I have tried to apply those answers to my code but it still doesn't work so I was hoping one of your guys would be able to have a look at my code and explain where I have gone wrong...

This is the code I have:

```
public class Square extends Rectangle{
String Colour;

    public Square (int x, int y, int h, int w, String Co){
    super (x,y,h,w);
    Colour=Co;
    System.out.println("Constructing a Square now");
    }
        public void showColour(){
        System.out.println("The colour of the square is " + Colour);
        }
}
```

Part two:

```
public class InheritProgram {
public static void main (String [] args){
Square One= new Square (10,20, 15, 15, "blue");

Square colour =new Square();
colour.showColour();

//GeometricShape center= new displayCenter();

}
}
```

And this is the error Im getting:

```
C:\Users\Karen\Documents\Java\Lab8-1\InheritProgram.java:5: error: constructor Square in class Square cannot be applied to given types;
Square colour =new Square();
               ^
  required: int,int,int,int,String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Why does your square constructor take height and width, a squares height always = it's width. The problem arises because you have to provide values when you create a new square, as you do here: Square One= new Square (10,20, 15, 15, "blue");, you must also do here: Square colour =new Square();

Answer (score 5):

In this line:

```
Square colour =new Square();
```

... you're trying to call a *parameterless* constructor for `Square` - but you haven't declared one. You've only declared the constructor with 5 parameters, so that's the one you have to use in order to create a new instance.

It's not clear why you're creating a second instance anyway - why don't you just call `showColour` on `One`?

(As an aside, I would *strongly* urge you to start following Java naming conventions, and making your fields private as well. If your indentation matches that in the question, fix that too - it'll make your code a lot easier to read. Most IDEs allow you to format the code very easily.)

Comment: Jon Skeet Thank you so much I've been staring at it for so long not even seeing what was so obviously wrong I didn't even notice it... Absolutely love you right now :D

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, you should have noticed stacktrace, which says it all.

```
Square colour =new Square();
required: int,int,int,int,String
found: no arguments
```

it says it requires the (only) constructor with params int,int,int,int,String, but you have called a no-arg constructor.